Determining resistor values in a push-pull power amplifier for a given speaker
I have kind of a newbie question. I did not find much convincing answers online, and I talked myself into a spiral where I am convinced by my calculations but am also convinced I am wrong. Basically, I wanted to know if my reasoning and calculations are way off or not.
The situation is the following: I want to design a classic class AB power amplifier, matching a 8Ω/50W speaker, with a ±48V symmetric supply. Leaving out bypass capacitors and taking only the last stage, this is the circuit I have in mind:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
To calculate the values of the collector resistors, I used the following reasoning:

With P = 50W and Z = 8Ω, the max current that can flow in the speaker is $$I_{max} = \sqrt{\frac{P}{Z}} = 2.5~\text{A}$$
Therefore, I must limit the current flowing through the BJT to 2.5 A; using Ohm's law: $$R = \frac{U}{I} = 19.2~\Omega$$
To avoid my resistor exploding violently, I need to provide enough wattage: $$P_{R} = R I^2 = 120~\text{W}$$
For the base resistors, I just assumed hFE = 50, yielding IB = 0.05 A, and then following the same kind of reasoning.

Of course, in practice, I would probably oversize the resistor to be below the limit and have a bit of headroom, but let us put that aside for the sake of the question.
Am I way off? Typically, I find my calculations "convincing", but needing a 120 W resistors seems to me like it is a lot. I know they exist, but do class AB amplifiers actually use such chunky resistors?
I hope you can help me making sense of that...
Thanks!

Forget calculations until you have the topology right. Remove the collector resistors. Use emitter resistors, with a higher voltage inter-base bias.

must limit the current [to the value computed with nominal impedance&power] No! Speaker impedance is complex, more so with (passive crossovers in) multiway speakers. And you ignore that the value you compute is average, a sine needing  almost 1.5 times that current peak.

I don't know why you think you need collector resistors. You don't need to 'limit the current flow' like that. What you do is design it so the transistors, speaker and supply voltages give the desired output power. For example, if you want 50 W into 8Ω you need
$$
V_{out} = 2\times\sqrt{2} \times \sqrt{50 W \times 8\Omega} = 56.56V_{pk-pk}
$$
add a bit for headroom and something like ±30 to ±35 V for the power rails would be about right.
Also in an AB amplifier you would usually have low value (< 1Ω) resistors between the emitters and the load to give a little negative feedback and balance currents if paralleled output transistors are used but the collectors usually go right to the power rails.

Why the  "2x" in the formula and then it gives 56.56V and you suggest 30-35V?

@Tyassin Peak to peak is 2 x RMS, So the total output swing will be 56V, add a bit extra for headroom, and then each rail is half of that.

Thx...now with the edit it makes more sense to me.

To me it seemed like, if you don't limit the current on the collector, then whenever it is fully open it might just let its full ISS through, which would destroy the speaker.
Also, you get voltage from the specification, I wonder if this is standard? Isn't it harder to "choose" a voltage in a reliable way rather than change resistors?
Last thing, I don't get your formula; you multiply watts and ohms and take the square root, which gives you amperes, right? Then how does it gets converted to volts? I get the coefficients in and of themselves but I am not sure of the "soundness" of the formula

@Crabe05 If it destroys the speaker when a transistor is fully on then the speaker wasn't rated high enough for the amplifier or the amplifier was rated too high for the speaker depending on which one you're basing the design on. Generally you design an amp for a certain max power out into a specified speaker impedance and leave it to the consumer to purchase the correct speakers.

As for the formula it's just working P=E²/Z around to get E = √(P*Z) and convert from RMS to Pk-Pk. You can check it in LTspice, just make a sine source with voltage 28.28 into an 8Ω load. That will give you 56.56 Pk-Pk and 50 W, I just checked it to make sure I hadn't messed it up in my 2AM sleep deprived answer :D

Ah yeah my bad I was confused for a moment I mixed too formulas... Sorry about that (not very fresh either).
Thank you for your help, I think I am starting to see how it's done now :-).

@Crabe05 Just a quick follow up on the unit conversions, you said "you multiply watts and ohms and take the square root, which gives you amperes, right?" No, look at it this way: power in watts is voltage time current, and current times resistance is volts, so if you break P * R down you get E * I * R, which gives you E * E, or voltage squared, take the square root and you get volts.
